# Zend Framework Sitemap and ACL

Tags: php, zend-framework, sitemap

I use Zend Framework sitemap like this:

```
echo $this->view->navigation()->sitemap();
```

in controller.

It works pretty well except one problem:

I have one big navigation for public part of the web together with client part navigation.

The problem is that for any entry which is forbidden for guests by ACL there is:

```
<url><loc>http://mywebsite.com/sitemap.xml/#</loc></url>
```

How can I tell sitemap not to print entries which are fobidden? In my current setting sitemap prints the line above for all entries in navigation which are forbidden by ACL.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0):

### Zend Framework 2.0

Your Navigation View Helper didn't know anything from your ACL in the Service Manager. Therefore you must pass your ACL and the current role to the view helper.

This can be done application wide by using the static setter of the AbstractNavigationHelper.

```
use Zend\Navigation\Service\AbstractNavigationFactory;
AbstractNavigationHelper::setDefaultRole('your current role');
AbstractNavigationHelper::setDefaultAcl('ACL object');
```

or directly when calling the view helper.

```
echo $this->view->navigation()->sitemap()
    ->setRole('your current role')
    ->setAcl('ACL object')
    ->render();
```

Comment: I have this in Bootstrap: protected function _initNavigations() 
    {        
        $navContainer = new Zend_Navigation($this->_getNavigationConfig());
        $this->_getView()->navigation($navContainer)->setAcl($this->_getAcl())->setRole(Zend_Registry::get('role'));
        
    } sorry for bad formating. The point is that I put my ACL into navigation helper in Bootstrap.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion now and I got the same result as before.

Comment: I think you are using Zend Framework 1.0, but it should be equal. Does your _getView() method Returns the view used to render the Content or do you create your own view instance?

Comment: I didn't notice 2.0, yes I'm using 1.11 but this is the same in 2.0 and 1.11.

Comment: _getView() just call: $this->getResource('view')

Comment: Maybe your view has not been bootstrap when you call the resource. Try to add:
    $this->bootstrap('view');

Comment: $this->bootstrap('view'); is the first command in my Bootstrap file.

Comment: What do you mean with first command? Normally the ZF reads out every method with _init*** and executes them in a "random" order (not alphabetically or something like that). With the `$this->bootstrap('bla')` you explicit say call the method _initBla() before executing the other code. So you can be sure that your depedencies initialized in the correct order.

Comment: _inits are imho executed in the same order that they appear in Bootstrap. I have $this->bootstrap('view'); in my first _init.